# Eclipse theme issues

Tags: eclipse, user-interface, colors, themes

Here is the Screenshot:

[image]

I've installed the moonrise theme for eclipse from here http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/eclipse-moonrise-ui-theme

It's odd that outline of my editor is white and and rest is dark...Someone help me with this issue!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Go to  Windows > General > Appearance > Theme Drop down.

Try changing it to Default theme, restart the Eclipse

Apply your Moonrise theme after restart.

See if it works.